# Highlight specific occurrence of word in text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to highlight a specific occurrence of a word in a text using jquery/js. Trying to find out if there are any existing libraries I can use. I read about mark.js but it does not offer the functionality I need.
Example Text: "In a home, there is a room, the room has a door" 
Highlight word: "room" 
 
Occurrence: 2
The second "room" in the text needs to be highlights.
Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide some clarification? Are you looking for something that highlights **specific occurrences** of a word, or the **last occurrence**?

Comment: @AlexH Thank you for your suggestion. I am looking for something that highlights specific occurrences of the word. Example, if there are 4 occurrences of room in the text. My "occurrence"  value is 2. Then I would highlight the 2nd term (room)

Comment: I suggest you look at my answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in the specific index of the token (character sequence you are looking for) to a function that takes the string, token, and index as parameters. You can now use the 2nd parameter of indexOf to update the beginning of where the string will be searched from using the last result:

```js
const highlighter = (string, token, index) => {
  let n = -1
  for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
    n = string.indexOf(token, n + 1)
  }
  return string.slice(0, n) + string.slice(n).replace(token, '<span class="highlight">' + token + '</span>')
}

const text = 'In a home, there is a room, the room has a door.<br>'
const firstRoom = highlighter(text, 'room', 0)
const secondRoom = highlighter(text, 'room', 1)

$('#result').append(firstRoom)
$('#result').append(secondRoom)
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The -1 is important since this function would otherwise miss the first token occurence if it appears at the start of the string.

Comment: Ah and a little FYI - passing in a non valid index for the token (i.e. passing in 2 when there are only 2 occurrences - remembering that it's 0 based) will not highlight anything and simply return the exact same string. The function is in this sense idempotent, but you won't see an error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// To replace all (commented out so it doesn't interfere with the other one)
/*
var p = document.getElementById("text"); // Gets the <p>
var text = p.innerText; // Gets the text it contains
var wordToReplace = "room"; // Which word should be replaced
var newtext = text.replaceAll(wordToReplace, '<span class="highlight">' + wordToReplace + '</span>'); // Replaces the word with the word wrapped in <span> tags, so it will look highlighted
p.innerHTML = newtext; // Change it back
*/


// To replace specific occurences
var paragraph = document.getElementById("text"); // Gets the <p>
var txt = paragraph.innerText; // Gets the text it contains
var textToReplace = 'room' // Word to be replaced
var replace = RegExp(textToReplace, 'g');
var matches = txt.matchAll(replace); // Gets all places where the text matches the word
var replacementPositions = [0, 2]; // Occurences which should be highlighted
var i = 0; // Which match this is; starts at 0
for (const match of matches) { // For each match...
  var text = match[0]; // The matching text
  var start = match.index; // Start position
  var end = match.index + text.length; // End position
  if (replacementPositions.includes(i)) { // If it should be replaced (in the replacementPositions array)
    var startText = txt.substring(0, start - 1); // Text before match
    var endText = txt.substring(start); // Text after match
    endText = endText.substring(text.length); // Removes matching text from the text after the match
    txt = startText + '<span class="highlight">' + text + '</span>' + endText; // Insert the match back in, wrapped in a <span>
  }
  i++; // Increment
}
paragraph.innerHTML = txt; // Set the paragraph text back
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">First: room. Another one: room. Last time: room</p>
```

The first method detects all occurrences of the word and wraps them in a `<span>`. The `<span>` has a style that sets the background color of the text, so it looks 'highlighted'.

The second method goes through every occurrence of the word and checks if it should be highlighted. If so, it does some operations that wrap that occurrence in a `<span>`, like the method above.

Comment: Think you may have slightly over engineered your function here. No need to do the extra work of finding all matches to then highlight only one or a few of them - you can do that in a single pass if you check if the index ("replacement positions") is desirable on each token match.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```js
let text = "In a home, there is a room, the room has a door.";
let search = "room";
var n = text.lastIndexOf(search);
text = text.slice(0, n) + text.slice(n).replace(search, "<span class='highlight'>" + search + "</span>");
$("#result").append(text);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: This works for this example, but it wouldn't work if the string was changed to have another instance of 'room'. Instead of highlighting specific occurrences, it just highlights the last one. My interpretation of the question is that the OP wants to be able to highlight specific occurrences of a word, rather than just the last one.

Comment: @AlexH Thanks for your feedback, it's possible that your interpretation of the question is the right one and in this case you already found an answer for that. I just read "The second "room" in the text needs to be highlights." in the question and in the example the second occurence is the last one. It would also be possible that in a sentence with 3 occurences of the same word the third occurence should be highlighted. It's up to the OP to get clarification.