# How can i transform a hashtag in a text to bold using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create a hashtag feature in my project but I don't know how to. I've tried many times but all to no avail.

Like for example:

I love #coding.

to be transformed to:

I love **#coding** using JQuery/JavaScript.
Any ideas?

Comment: You have to parse your whole string and replace word start with "#" with formatted word in bold style.

Comment: Can you write a code that shows how to do that?

Comment: Run a regex to find all occurrences of words starting with # and wrap that word around <b></b>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554208/javascript-regex-match-any-word-that-starts-with-in-a-string

Comment: @Chris I want to see your implementation of code. 
where you want to display your text in Text Box or in any html element ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+highlight+word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight specific occurrence of word in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222185/highlight-specific-occurrence-of-word-in-text)

Comment: @Yuvraj Mule, In a p tag

Comment: Have you checked my answer ?
you can use <p> tag instead of <div> in my answer and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chirs try this in your webpage

```js
function FormatText()
  {
  var txt =document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML;
   var matches = txt.match(/#\w+/g);
   if(matches==null)
    return;
    
   for(i=0;i<matches.length;i++)
   {
     txt=txt.replace(matches[i],"<b>"+ matches[i] +"</b>")
   }
   document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML=txt;
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="FormatText();">
  <div id="mytext">
    I love #coding using JQuery/JavaScript on #WebPages.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked....